# Metadata export error when running on large directory structures

Tags: windows, file, powershell, directory, metadata

This script exports the basic file metadata in PowerShell to a .csv.

```
PS K:\> Get-childitem -recurse -file | select-object length,lastwritetime,fullname | export-csv filelist.csv -notypeinformation
```

It works great on simple directory structures of 10-20K files, but when I run it on 500K+ files of complex, multi-level directory structures it freezes or gives me error:

```
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-childitem -recurse -file | select-object length,lastwritetime,ful ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (0:Int32) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CallDepthOverflow
```

Is this a problem with the `-recurse` or else?  Using PowerShell 5 1 (Major Minor).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test to see how long the filepaths are.

If the filepaths are more than 248 characters... That may be why you are getting the error.

**To check to see if any come back with more than 248 characters you can do**

```
Get-childitem "filepath" -recurse  | % {
    $filepath = $_.FullName
    $charactercount = ($filepath | Measure-Object -Character).Characters
    If ($charactercount -gt 248){write-host $filepath}
}
```

Comment: `cmd /c dir /s /b |? {$_.length -gt 248}` is this good way to check?

Comment: im not an expert at commandline but I modified my answer with the powershell code you can use.

Comment: Tried on 1.5 TB, 400K files of all sorts. It gave a .csv output with 50K lines (as opened with Notepad++) but still an error message below. There are no path names above 246.

`The script failed due to call depth overflow.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-childitem -recurse -file | select-object length,lastwritetime,ful ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (0:Int32) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CallDepthOverflow`

Comment: do you get an error when just launching `Get-childitem -recurse -file | select-object length,lastwritetime,fullname` ?

Comment: you nailed it! thank you. running w/o export (as you suggested) revealed an "infinite loop" hung-up (same set of lines kept repeating over and over again in the powershell window. i went to that problem directory and there was a weird empty directory with no name (zero characters), which i deleted. thereafter, the script and export runs fine. so as you suggested  long path names and one abnormal directory was the culprit.

Comment: awesome! Glad i could help!